# Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm encountering this error that I don't know how to solve.

My project is React + Redux Toolkit and the error is thrown out just in a cartSlice.ts:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface CartState {
  name: string
  initialState: {
    cart: {}[]
  }
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    cart: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemInCart = state.cart.find(
        (item:any) => item.id === action.payload.id)
      if (itemInCart) {
        itemInCart.quantity++;
      } else {
        state.cart.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 })
      }
    },
    removeItem: (state, action) => {
      const removeItem = state.cart.filter(
        (item) => item.id !== action.payload)
      state.cart = removeItem
    },
  },
})

export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer
export const { addToCart, removeItem } = cartSlice.actions
```

The errors that I'm encountering:

> Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'never'.
>
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
>
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't define it inside initialState and settled for the object {}[].

your interface may look like this:

```js
type TCart = {
  id?: string;
  quantity?: number;
};

interface CartState {
  name: string;
  initialState: {
    cart: TCart[];
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here :

```
    cart: {}[]
```

The never type represents the type of values that never occur.

Cart is inferred to be an array of objects with zero keys. According to TS, there is no way you will find an element using this because `id` key does not exist on any item in `cart` array.

```
const itemInCart = cart.find(
        (item:any) => item.id === 1
      );
```

So `itemInCart` type is inferred to be `never`. And `quantity` key does not exist on never.

This is why you get both these errors:

```
Property 'quantity' does not exist on type 'never'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.
```

Similarly, the following statement

```
state.cart.push({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 })
```

causes

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Do something like:

```
interface CartState {
  name: string
  initialState: {
    cart: { quantity : number ,id : number }[]
  }
}
```